# How to install opencv with tbb enabled using mingw

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, mingw, tbb

How to install Opencv with TBB enabled?

I tried the following:

1) Downloaded the TBB package.

2) Build using the below command

```
 mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=ia32 runtime=mingw default
```

3) I set the Environmental variable path as "d:\tbb\build\windows_ia32_gcc_mingw_release

3) Now using cmake, I enabled "WITH_TBB" and compiled the opencv.

its throwing the below error.

```
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_core245.dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -ltbb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_core245.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I missing anything...
Please advice..

Comment: I am trying to do the same, you got much further than I did! Where did you find the documentation? If I get to your same point I will do my best to help :)

Comment: @Antonio I couldnt find any Docs. I solved the problem by setting the TBB bin directory to PATH.

Comment: @Antonio I couldnt find time to make a doc on it.. If you tell what problem you are facing, I amy help you..

Comment: I can build tbb separately, but
I cannot prevent opencv (2.4.5) to download its own tbb package when I run cmake with TBB enabled.
Then opencv tries to build tbb, but fails.
I cannot configure opencv to use the tbb version I downloaded and built.

Comment: @Antonio Please tell me how you are building. If you are using CMAKE disable "BUILD_TBB" option and enable "WITH_TBB".

Comment: Of course, you are right, it was so obvious!! I was generically advised "activate any TBB flag" and then I did and turned off the brain :P Now I disabled BUILD_TBB and I am getting your same error...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32159/discussion-between-2vision2-and-antonio)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, the following worked out for removing the tbb linking error:

(Assuming you have already built tbb, as you are already explaining in your question)

- From CMake, configure one time OpenCV
- Enable `WITH_TBB`, be careful **not** enabling `BUILD_TBB`: the automatic downloading and building of OpenCV failed miserably for me despite many efforts. If you had previously enabled `BUILD_TBB`, my suggestion is to restart from the beginnning, clearing cmake cache.
- Configure a second time OpenCV
- Now some variables should appear: `TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS`. For me I set the following values (respectively):

  `tbb41_20130314oss/include`
- 2 new variables appears: `TBB_STDDEF_PATH` and `TBB_LIB_DIR`. They are assigned some apparently reasonable values. For me, `TBB_STDDEF_PATH` was correct, but `TBB_LIB_DIR` was not! So I corrected it to be:

  `tbb41_20130314oss/build/windows_ia32_gcc_mingw4.8.1_release`

  and I left `TBB_STDDEF_PATH` as it was:

  `tbb41_20130314oss/include/tbb/tbb_stddef.h`
- Configure a **third** time
- Finally, click Generate, and you are ready to build `mingw32-make -j7`
- Once you start using the opencv library, make sue the tbb DLLs are in your path

Comment: I now realize I did some mess on explaining how many variables appear after the second configure. But I don't have a quick way to try it again. If anybody tries this guide and see again what should be done exactly, please feel free to edit.