# CMake error: BUILD_TBB option supports Windows on ARM only

Tags: opencv, cmake, tbb

I am trying to build libraries with CMake for a vision detection system to be built in OpenCV using Visual Studio 2012's C++ compiler. After a lot of fixing of configurations, installation of Qt 5 and also Openni, I am still getting the following errors from the CMake configuration step:

```
Checking for Windows (Phone) Platform SDK 8.0/8.1
Checking for Visual Studio 2012/2013
WARNING, OpenNI library directory (set by OPENNI_LIB_DIR variable) is not     found or does not have OpenNI libraries.
WARNING, OpenNI include directory (set by OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR variable) is not found or does not have OpenNI include files.
WARNING, PrimeSensor Module binaries directory (set by     OPENNI_PRIME_SENSOR_MODULE_BIN_DIR variable) is not found or does not have   PrimeSensor Module binaries.
Looking for Mfapi.h
Looking for Mfapi.h - found
Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindIntelPerCSDK.cmake:17 (message):
Intel Perceptual Computing SDK library directory (set by INTELPERC_LIB_DIR
variable) is not found or does not have Intel Perceptual Computing SDK
libraries.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:291 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:482 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/tbb/CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
  BUILD_TBB option supports Windows on ARM only!

  Use regular official TBB build instead of the BUILD_TBB option!


 Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "C:/OpenCV/opencv/lib/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: How do you call CMake? It does not find OpenNI and it complains that you have passed some weired flag to build build TBB. Where does your TBB installation come from?

Comment: I use the cmake gui. I already have Visual Studio 2012 as the compiler and it picks it up fine. I have not got a clue what TBB is, sorry I am a complete novice when it comes to TBB.

Comment: Funny thing is I installed openNI on my laptop, so why does cmake not be able to find it? Should i tell it which directory to look into like I did the other applications? If so how do I alert it to the openni directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **cmake_gui**, you can quickly disable BUILD_TBB variable. If you want [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org), you have to build it separately by yourself, and then you can use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767464/how-to-install-opencv-with-tbb-enabled-using-mingw/17269617#17269617) to activate it in OpenCV.

Comment: What does TBB stand for? Why would I need it? How do I disable it? Sorry you have to take me step by step like a baby if you dont mind.

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman: TBB stands for Threading Building Blocks, Antonio even linked to their homepage.

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman In my answer I provided you a link to TBB. Did you run cmake_gui? From there is straightforward to set CMake variables.

Comment: I dont think I need TBB because i dont think i am doing parallel processing. All I need cmake to do is to build the opencv libraries for me so I can use them in a vision detection project in Visual studio. So the next question is how do I disable the Build_TBB variable? To say that it is straight forward does not really answer the question. Pretend that I am a baby or a 5 year old kid and explain to me how to disable TBB. Thanks Antonio.

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman Then you should change your profile description :) In the comments under your question you said you have cmake_gui opened, add a screenshot to your question please.

Comment: Hello Antonio, The screenshot output is shown in the question as though it is code.