# How to build the opencv with tbb using mingw for windows?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, tbb

I have tried this following steps,

1) Downloaded the TBB package.

2) Build using the below command

```
mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=ia32 runtime=mingw default
```

3) I set the Environmental variable path

4) Now using ***cmake***, I enabled "**WITH_TBB**" and compiled the opencv.

after that i got an error as

```
[33%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_core245.dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -ltbb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_core245.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can any one say how to overcome this issue and how to build the tbb for windows mingw ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install opencv with tbb enabled using mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767464/how-to-install-opencv-with-tbb-enabled-using-mingw)

Comment: using cmake gui: typically after enabling "WITH_TBB" (and clicking "configure" or how it is named once) there will come up a new field (colored red) where to tell the TBB lib path.

Comment: yea , the new field came in that i gave the tbb include directory path to it.

Comment: duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767464/how-to-install-opencv-with-tbb-enabled-using-mingw